# Huge computation cost or large computation cost? which one should I use?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I see this [huge or large. Which one should I use?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16134/huge-or-large-which-one-should-i-use)

I got

> However, something huge is surprisingly large or excessively large. If something is large, but about as large as can be expected, then it is not huge.

I have some doubt as

Due to `huge` computation cost, this method is not widely used.

Due to `large` computation cost, this method is not widely used.

Need some suggestion.

Comment: "Costs" are usually spoken of as *high*, not *large*. *Huge* is used to mean either excessively large or excessively high.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks for the clarification. What if I remove `cost` term from both of these above sentences? Does the rule remain same?

Comment: major cost is the most formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both huge and large would be acceptable in this situation. Huge would emphasise the size of the cost more, but large would more likely be used in formal contexts.

To describe the cost, you should be using the adjectival form of computation - computational. Given that you are referring to one unique thing (the cost), you should be using the definite article as well. Your sentences would then become:

> Due to the huge computational cost, this method is not widely used.
>
> Due to the large computational cost, this method is not widely used.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use large. 'High' sounds much better. 'Large' suggests spatial dimension, while 'high' is more about the number you are obtaining in the benchmark. 'Huge' is non-technical and too informal. As a computer scientist, I wouldn't be persuaded by your comment unless you give some complexity measure or cost analysis.

Comment: I agree with your comment about informality. That was the first thing I thought of when I read the queston.